# EXOR Gate cryptology

Tags: encryption, logic, xor

Hi i wanted to convert the following (01101010) into cipher text  using the following random binary data: 1100

Could anybody help me do this and also show me how to work it out?

Thanks

Comment: No responses in a week can be a bit annoying or demoralising. It probably implies that you need to give some more detail in the question. What do you already know about using XOR to encrypt a string of bits and what is the issue over which you are stuck?

Answer (score 0):

The original text is eight bits long. Therefore, the key has to be repeated to achieve matching lengths.

```
Text original  01101010
Key repeated   11001100
Text encrypted 10100110
```

To get a certain bit of the encoded text, one has to calculate the `XOR` or the original text bit and the respective key bit. For example: The first bit evaluates to `0 xor 1 = 1`

Note that you can retrieve the original text from the encoded text by re-applying the same procedure as during the encryption.